# What does "a good" mean?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I have seen the following sentence on a news web site, which was telling about a volcano eruption. A sentence including "a good" surprised me, as I have not seen it used like this. Here is the sentence:

> "...You could hear and feel the eruption a good half a mile away, and the closer you got, the more you could feel it..."

What does *"a good"* mean here? Does it mean *"they could hear it well"* or does it mean *"they could hear it from a distance which was as far as a mile long".*

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence, **good** is an adjective modifying "a half a mile".

[The meaning is definition 1d(2) at Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good): **full**

So "a **good** half a mile" means "a *full* half a mile", and it's a way of emphasizing that it was definitely half a mile away that you could hear and feel the eruption.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out, though, that _good_ in this sense is often used rather informally. For example, I might say, "I saw an accident a good half mile down the road," when it might have only been .46 miles down the road. It's often more like an estimate than a confirmation.

Comment: I think [the full OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/79925?rskey=rMomu1&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) definition **I-11 (a)** *Used to emphasize that a quantity, number, etc., is **at least** as great as, and **quite probably greater** than, stated* is more specific to OP's exact context. But sadly, that link is behind a paywall for most users here.